# Error with collection_check_boxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-4-2-1

how resolve this error:

**SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: functionalities.profile_id: SELECT "functionalities".* FROM "functionalities" WHERE "functionalities"."profile_id" = 1**

This is my _form.html.erb

```
<h3>Add functionalities</h3>
  <% if current_user.admin? %>
    <%= f.collection_check_boxes :functionality_ids, Functionality.all, :id, :description %>
  <% else %>
    <%= f.collection_check_boxes :functionality_ids, Functionality.where(profile_id: current_user.profile.id), :id, :description %>
  <% end %>
```

Profile.rb

```
  has_many :users
  has_many :profile_functionalities
  has_many :functionalities, through: :profile_functionalities
  belongs_to :manager
  belongs_to :agent
```

Functionality.rb

```
 # Nothing here for now
```

ProfileFunctionality.rb

```
  belongs_to :profile
  belongs_to :functionality
```

I think that I need make a join, because the error is in when I'm on **else**.

Comment: why not just `current_user.profile.functionalities` in place of `Functionality.where(profile_id: current_user.profile.id)`? Since you posted nothing for the `Functionality` model it hard to determine this relationship works but I would assume that it does not have a `profile_id` since this is what your join table `ProfileFunctionality` is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you currently have is a many-to-many relation, so functionality has no `profile_id` column. You need to find the profile first, then get the functionalities related to it:

```
Profile.find(current_user.profile_id).functionalities
```

If `current_user` is itself an activerecord object, you can just do:

```
current_user.profile.functionalities
```

In general, you don't want to specifically reference *_id columns, and instead let rails do the translation for you.